# Iterar con VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Soy nuevo con VueJS y estoy tratando de iterar con v-for un objeto JSON con el que estoy trabajando, el problema esta en que una de las llaves son números seguidos, por mas que intento no logro dar con la solución agradecería su ayuda

```
{
    "1": {
      "ourid": 1,
      "title": "Afghanistan",
      "code": "AF",
    },
    "2": {
      "ourid": 2,
      "title": "Albania",
      "code": "AL",
    },
    "3": {
    ...
    ..
```

```
<select  v-model="contrySelected">
    <option v-for="contryStat in contryStats" :value=contryStat.code">{{ contryStat.title }}</option>
</select>
```

Necesito acceder a la información como title y code
Gracias

Comment: ¿Nos muestras por favor lo que has intentado?

Comment: Claro acabo de editar la publicación

Comment: Ahí tienes 2 jsons separados, ¿Están dentro de uno mismo? O ¿Forman parte de un array? Dependiendo de eso, se iterará de una manera o de otra..

Comment: Hola @Grommy acabo  de editar el ejemplo, ahora se parece mas al JSON que me entregan

Comment: Entiendo. Ahí va mi proposición de código entonces :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se que seguramente habrá mejores respuestas pero te comento lo siguiente:

- Tendrás que llevar a cabo un doble `v-for` para que de esta forma puedas iterar sobre los valores de ambos json
- Con el primer `v-for` accedes a la clave principal que para este ejemplo se llama datos y almacenamos sus valores en la variable `elemento`
- Con el segundo `v-for` el cual te dará la opción de iterar las clave y valores los almacenamos estos últimos en la variable `pais`
- Con esta última que se llama `pais` ya puedes hacer la sintaxis de `clave.valor` donde valor puede ser `title`; entonces estás iterando obtienes los nombres y llenas tu select option

Te dejo este ejemplo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
      <select v-for="elemento in datos">
        <option value="" v-for="pais in elemento">{{ pais.title }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
          el: `#app`,
          data: {
            datos: [{
              "1": {
                  "ourid": 1,
                  "title": "Afghanistan",
                  "code": "AF"
              },
              "2": {
                  "ourid": 2,
                  "title": "Albania",
                  "code": "AL"
              }
            }]
          }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Excelente, es justo lo que estaba buscando, no sabia que podías anidar de esa forma los v-for, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si posees un json, el código debería llevar a cabo una iteración sobre sus distintas llaves:

```
<select  v-model="contrySelected">
    <option v-for="(item, key) in contryStats" :value=item.code">{{ item.title }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Lo siento sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: Disculpa, fallo mío. No es 'items', es tu variable, 'contryStats' :-)). Modificado.

Comment: Adapte la variable en mi código y sigue sin funcionar, sigo creyendo que es la key que muestra antes de acceder a los datos, que problema :/